# dbt deps command results in "Unable to connect to registry hub"

Tags: dbt

When running `dbt deps`, I get back this error message:

```
Running with dbt=0.17.0
Error sending message, disabling tracking
Encountered an error:
Unable to connect to registry hub
```

What's happening here, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's worth understanding what's going on here. It looks like you're trying to install a package from the dbt hub site (hub.getdbt.com) — if you open up your `packages.yml` file, you'll find something like this:

```
packages:
  - hub: package-owner/package-name
    version: 0.1.0
```

When you run `dbt deps` (at a high level):

1. dbt sends a request to hub.getdbt.com
2. From hub.getdbt.com, a request is sent to GitHub to download the package.
3. The package is copied into your project

This error occurs if dbt cannot connect to the hub site after sending a network request repeatedly. First off, we recommend you retry the `dbt deps` command — sometimes it's just a blip in connectivity that goes away on the second try.

If the error persists, there may be a few different reasons for it:

- hub.getdbt.com might be unavailable. This happens but is relatively rare. You can navigate to hub.getdbt.com to check if this is the case. Also check the [Netlify status page](https://www.netlifystatus.com/) to see if there are any issues.
- GitHub might be down — you can check this by going to the [GitHub status page](https://www.githubstatus.com/).
- Finally, it may be that a firewall rule or antivirus software on your computer is rejecting the request. Talk to your IT team to find out if this is the case and whether that restriction can be removed.

We generally recommend using the hub syntax for packages, however if you need to work around it, you can consider using the git syntax ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management/#git-packages)) or installing the package from a local directory ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management/#local-packages))

Comment: might be worth updating to use the `package:` key instead of `hub:`?